# How to simplify $3^{(2\log_335)}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$3^{2\log_35}$

How do I simplify this? This is what I have done so far:

$2\log_35=\log_35^2=\log_3(25)$

$3^{\log_3(25)}$

What do I do from here?
And the answer is one of these mixed solutions:

$0$

$-2$

$-\frac\pi4$

$\frac1{x+2}$

$\pm \frac4 {25}$

$25$

$30°$

$2$

$3$

$5$

$\pi$

$\frac\pi3$

$(-\infty, 2)$

$4(x+1)^2+3$

$-\frac{\sqrt2}2$

$-\frac{\sqrt3}2$

$\frac{\sqrt2}2$

Comment: Jesus, talk about multiple choice...

Comment: eh. sorry about that, but blame the teach not me

Comment: @circpis-thanks for editing my work-Am new here that's why

Comment: Is this a matching question? Do you have a whole bunch of expressions on the left you need to match to values on the right? It seems odd to give this many options for one question.

Comment: Nope, its a homework pkt, to see if your eligible to take AP calc next yr.

Comment: @user2357112 That's the best explanation I can come up with, too. Otherwise this is a *really* funny situation. Also, anyone else realize that the answer is not any of the ones given in the "multiple choice"?

Comment: @MichaelT: 25 is in there, right above 30°.

Comment: @user2357112 Oops, I was going with the $35$ in the title

Comment: @MichaelT sry bout the awk situation, but like i said before, dont blame me, blame the teach

Comment: @user2357112 sry bout the awk situation, but like i said before, dont blame me, blame the teach

Comment: @MEE: this is not an "equation" you are trying to "solve." It is an *expression* you are trying to *simplify*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\displaystyle m\log a=\log a^m$ when both the logarithms remain defined

$$\displaystyle\implies3^{(2\log_35)}=3^{\log_3(5^2)}$$

Now $\displaystyle a^{\log_ab}=b$ when the logarithm remains defined